# What is an associative container?

Tags: c++, data-structures, associative-array

I am writing a paper about a certain new data structure. This structure holds `(key, value)` pairs and supports fast lookup by the `key`.

**Can I call it an associative container in my paper?**

Wikipedia contains the definition of associative containers [only in the context of C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers_%28C++%29).
Is the concept of **associative container** a C++ thing?

The entry on [Associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array#cite_note-ms-2) seems better. It defines the **associative array** in terms of 4 operations:

1. the addition of pairs to the collection
2. the removal of pairs from the collection
3. the modification of the values of existing pairs
4. the lookup of the value associated with a particular key

Unfortunately I cannot find very good references to this definition. Do you know of any relevant sources that I can cite?

Comment: It is an associative container if the keys are not necessarily contiguous integers.

Comment: Which implies the keys are integers. An associative array or dictionary can have any type of keys.

Comment: java also has `Map`, as well as `HashMap` which are associative, as well as containers, so i'm pretty sure you can call it that. after all, an array is technically a container, isn't it?

Comment: I wonder if template metaprograms can be seen as a special case of using associative containers. The template specializing on type being the "container" and the type being the "key".

Comment: @Hulk I think you confused [scicomp.SE] with [cs.SE].

Comment: @delnan you are correct. The sites look terribly similar, and the names are just too close. Even the question titles do little to make the difference more obvious. However: [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is where this question is probably most appropriate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An associative container is any container that is not necessarily indexed with sequential integers that start with the base for the language (0 in most of the C-based languages, 1 for some others).  If the data structure in your paper meets that requirement, it is an associative container.

As a general rule, don't use Wikipedia as a source for an academic paper.

Comment: `As a general rule, don't use Wikipedia as a source for an academic paper.` yes, use sources cited by wikipedia.

Comment: I'd disagree. Visual Basic has arrays using sequential indices, but with arbitrary lower bounds. Nobody would call that an associative container..

Comment: @MSalters What VB arrays are you talking about?  VB arrays start at index 0 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx).

Comment: @Zac: That's for .Net compatibility, and [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23s0z8fy(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: @MSalters That seems to indicate that feature is no longer valid, correct?

Comment: Indeed, VB arrays were not compatible with .Net arrays because of that.

Answer (score 11):

To see a real-world example of associative containers in C++, look at `std::set` and `std::map`. They are very good examples to learn from. Typically, with associative containers, there is a key and a value and the key is unique. Some people who are new to data structures often wonder how a `std::set` is associative as it only has one thing! In a `std::set`, the key and the value are the same. In a map, the key can be different from the value.

`std::set` (the key is the value)    :

```
 a    
 b    
 c
```

`std::map` (the key and value may be different)    :

```
 1 -> a    
 2 -> b    
 3 -> c
```

A `std::map` could also be used exactly like a `std::set` although it makes no sense to do this when `std::set` is available and if your data look like this, then just use a `std::set`:

```
 a -> a
 b -> b
 c -> c
```

So knowing that, if you wanted to implement your own associative container, you could just implement a map and when someone wants to use it as a set, just make the key equal the value. In fact, I believe [Go only implemented maps](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177428/sets-data-structure-in-golang) and they can be used as maps or sets.